# Datastore Export Operator Permission Error from Google Composer Airflow Environment

Tags: python, airflow, datastore, google-cloud-composer

I am receiving a permission error running my airflow DAG under the datastore_export_operator.DatastoreExportOperator task.  The airflow env was created using google composer and has the default google_cloud_datastore_default connection, but i am still receiving this error:

```
[2019-07-19 01:08:36,618] {models.py:1796} ERROR - <HttpError 403 when requesting https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{project-name}:export?alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission">
```

TO note - I can successfully access bigquery and cloud storage using the default connections, but i am unable to access datastore

my full dag is below

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators import datastore_export_operator
bucket_name = 'my-bucket-name'
datastore_conn_id = 'google_cloud_datastore_default'
cloud_storage_conn_id = 'google_cloud_storage_default'
overwrite_existing = 'true'
entity_filter = {'kinds' : [''], 'namespaceIds' : ['']}
default_args = {
  'owner': 'Jordan',
  'depends_on_past': False,
  'start_date': datetime(2019, 7, 18),
  'email_on_failure': True, 
  'email': ['jordan@jordan.com'], 
  'retries': 1, 
  'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2), 
}

dag = DAG('novelty.stats.adunit.daily', 
  schedule_interval='@daily',
  default_args=default_args
)

t1 = datastore_export_operator.DatastoreExportOperator(
  dag=dag,
  task_id='ad_unit_config_to_storage',
  bucket=bucket_name,
  entity_filter=entity_filter,
  datastore_conn_id=datastore_conn_id,
  cloud_storage_conn_id='cloud_storage_conn_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an IAM policy issue. I would recommend adding the following IAM role [roles/datastore.importExportAdmin](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/access/iam#iam_roles) explicitly to your Composer environment [service account](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.environments#NodeConfig).

I also noticed something odd in the error log `https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{project-name}` where the project-name wasn't resolved to your GCP project ID. It might be a red herring though due to the fact that the log was produced by `models.py`. Let's see whether the IAM policy change fixes this problem.